# Ошибка 500 при выполнении запроса /wd/hub/sessions к docker-selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, docker, vnc

Запускаем Selenium-сервер ([elgalu/docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium)):

```
require('child_process').execSync(
  `docker run -d --name="selenium-tester-3" ` +
  `-p 40002:24444 -p 40012:25900 --shm-size=1g ` +
  `-e NOVNC=false -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480 -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola ` +
  `elgalu/selenium`
);
```

Подключаемся к нему через [chimpy](https://thebrainfamily.github.io/chimpy/):

```
[chimp][session-manager] checking connection to selenium server
[11:40:53]  COMMAND     GET      "/wd/hub/status"
[11:40:53]  DATA                {}
[11:40:53]  RESULT              {
  "ready":true,"message":"Hub has capacity",
  "build":{"revision":"e82be7d358","time":"2018-11-14T08:25:53","version":"3.141.59"},
  "os":{"arch":"amd64","name":"Linux","version":"4.15.0-1014-gcp"},
  "java":{"version":"1.8.0_191"}
}
```

[Пытаемся выполнить запрос](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/chimpy/blob/d859c610d247c4199945b280b0f3a14c076153c7/src/lib/session-manager.js#L200) `/wd/hub/sessions`, но получаем ошибку `500`:

```
[chimp][session-manager] requesting sessions from http://localhost:40002/wd/hub/sessions
[chimp][session-manager] received error Server Error [500]
[chimp][session-manager] response {  
  "sessionId": null,  
  "status": 13,  
  "value": {  
    "class": "org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException",  
    "error": "unknown error",  
    "message": "Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]",  
    "stackTrace": [  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions",  
        "fileName": "ActiveTestSessions.java",  
        "lineNumber": 120,  
        "methodName": "getExistingSession"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",  
        "fileName": "DefaultGridRegistry.java",  
        "lineNumber": 387,  
        "methodName": "getExistingSession"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler",  
        "fileName": "RequestHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 241,  
        "methodName": "getSession"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler",  
        "fileName": "RequestHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 123,  
        "methodName": "process"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet",  
        "fileName": "DriverServlet.java",  
        "lineNumber": 85,  
        "methodName": "process"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet",  
        "fileName": "DriverServlet.java",  
        "lineNumber": 63,  
        "methodName": "doGet"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",  
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",  
        "lineNumber": 687,  
        "methodName": "service"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",  
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",  
        "lineNumber": 790,  
        "methodName": "service"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder",  
        "fileName": "ServletHolder.java",  
        "lineNumber": 865,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler",  
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 535,  
        "methodName": "doHandle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 146,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler",  
        "fileName": "SecurityHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 548,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper",  
        "fileName": "HandlerWrapper.java",  
        "lineNumber": 132,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 257,  
        "methodName": "nextHandle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler",  
        "fileName": "SessionHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 1595,  
        "methodName": "doHandle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 255,  
        "methodName": "nextHandle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler",  
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 1340,  
        "methodName": "doHandle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 203,  
        "methodName": "nextScope"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler",  
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 473,  
        "methodName": "doScope"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler",  
        "fileName": "SessionHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 1564,  
        "methodName": "doScope"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 201,  
        "methodName": "nextScope"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler",  
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 1242,  
        "methodName": "doScope"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler",  
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",  
        "lineNumber": 144,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper",  
        "fileName": "HandlerWrapper.java",  
        "lineNumber": 132,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server",  
        "fileName": "Server.java",  
        "lineNumber": 503,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel",  
        "fileName": "HttpChannel.java",  
        "lineNumber": 364,  
        "methodName": "handle"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection",  
        "fileName": "HttpConnection.java",  
        "lineNumber": 260,  
        "methodName": "onFillable"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback",  
        "fileName": "AbstractConnection.java",  
        "lineNumber": 305,  
        "methodName": "succeeded"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest",  
        "fileName": "FillInterest.java",  
        "lineNumber": 103,  
        "methodName": "fillable"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2",  
        "fileName": "ChannelEndPoint.java",  
        "lineNumber": 118,  
        "methodName": "run"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill",  
        "fileName": "EatWhatYouKill.java",  
        "lineNumber": 333,  
        "methodName": "runTask"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill",  
        "fileName": "EatWhatYouKill.java",  
        "lineNumber": 310,  
        "methodName": "doProduce"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill",  
        "fileName": "EatWhatYouKill.java",  
        "lineNumber": 168,  
        "methodName": "tryProduce"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill",  
        "fileName": "EatWhatYouKill.java",  
        "lineNumber": 126,  
        "methodName": "run"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread",  
        "fileName": "ReservedThreadExecutor.java",  
        "lineNumber": 366,  
        "methodName": "run"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool",  
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",  
        "lineNumber": 765,  
        "methodName": "runJob"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2",  
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",  
        "lineNumber": 683,  
        "methodName": "run"  
      },  
      {  
        "className": "java.lang.Thread",  
        "fileName": "Thread.java",  
        "lineNumber": 748,  
        "methodName": "run"  
      }  
    ],  
    "stacktrace": "org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]\n\tat org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession(ActiveTestSessions.java:120)\n\tat org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry.getExistingSession(DefaultGridRegistry.java:387)\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.getSession(RequestHandler.java:241)\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:123)\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)\n\tat org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doGet(DriverServlet.java:63)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)\n\tat org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"  
  }  
}
```

В чём может быть проблема с запросом `/wd/hub/sessions`?
На все остальные запросы, в т.ч. на `/wd/hub/session`, этот сервер реагирует нормально.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719170/error-500-when-executing-query-wd-hub-sessions-to-docker-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [elgalu/docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium) запускается сервер Selenium Grid, который не может сам обработать запрос `/wd/hub/sessions`. В данном случае внутри два Noda'a (Chrome и Firefox):

[image: Gride Console]

Но можно обратиться к одному из Node'ов непосредственно, пробросив соответствующий порт наружу. Так для взаимодействия с Node'ом ChromeDriver потребуется порт `25550`:

```
require('child_process').execSync(
  `docker run -d --name="selenium-tester-3" ` +
  `-p 40002:25550 -p 40012:25900 --shm-size=1g ` +
  `-e NOVNC=false -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480 -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola ` +
  `elgalu/selenium`
);
```